# how to deploy .wsp to all servers in the Sharepoint 2007 Farm

Tags: 2007, solution-package, stsadm, farm-solution

What is the stsadm -o command for deploying .wsp solution file into all servers in the SharePoint 2007 Farm?

My second question is: How i can check with already deployed .wsp solution if it is deployed on single server or on all servers in the farm?

Answer (score 1):

This is two step Process:

First you have to Add the solution into Farm

```
stsadm.exe -o addsolution -filename yoursolutionpackage.wsp
```

Second, You have to deploy it.

```
stsadm -o deploysolution -name yoursolutionpackagename.wsp -url http://sp-mach/ -local  -force
```

Check this for more info:
http://www.ironspeed.com/Designer/9.1.1/WebHelp/Part_VI/SharePoint_Solution_Package_WSP_Deployment.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename C:\solution.wsp
```

This is from a farm level, so it applies to the entire farm, whether you have one server or 10 servers. There is a page in Central Admininstration -> Operations -> Solution Management that will tell you the deployment state of all the solutions in the farm and whether or not they were deployed to a specific web application(s) or globally.